# Cannot get speech-arrow on text box pointing toward user and bot messages for each of their messages

Tags: botframework

I need to get a speech arrow included within my chatbot to point at where the message has been sent from.  I have not found anything relating to this within any of the docs, but I have seen this design implemented in several of the example images within the same docs.

To clarify, my text chat is rounded without anything jutting out to indicate who sent the message.  The effect I am going for is what is seen in the 'test in web chat' section of the azure docs listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-nodejs-tutorial-build-bot-framework-sample

Comment: Are you asking about how to customize the appearance of Web Chat, or are you using a different channel?

Comment: @KyleDelaney Yes I am asking about customizing web chat.  Specifically I want to add an arrow to the speech bubbles, pointing the direction from which the senders avatar is oriented.  In the azure test environment, this arrow appears and is created through an SVG element added to the speech bubble.

Comment: Were you able to determine that by inspecting the HTML?

Comment: @KyleDelaney Yes, I used the chrome console to inspect the HTML.

Comment: @KyleDelaney Hi Kyle, still hoping to get some response on this..

Comment: Sorry to make you wait. I'm still working on this, but if you'd like to investigate yourself then please have a look at the samples in the Web Chat repo: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples

Comment: Okay, thank you Kyle

Comment: Hi Ellbroach. I've discovered that "Test in Web Chat" looks like that because it's using Web Chat v3 instead of v4. If all you want to do is put those arrows in your Web Chat then this can be accomplished just by using Web Chat v3, but I should warn you that v3 is not well supported and much harder to customize. Would you like to apply that look in Web Chat v4?

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Comment: Hi @KyleDelaney , yes I would like to apply that look in Web Chat v4, if that is possible.  Thank you.

Comment: You could try creating your own Direct Line client, but I think the best option is going to be waiting for the feature to be implemented in Web Chat. Please go ahead and mark my answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

I've determined that this is not possible using the current customization abilities of Web Chat v4. It looks like you've already found the GitHub issue where progress on this feature can be tracked: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/1658